# Data do not fall in Angular template

Tags: javascript, angular

I have component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'fx-content',
    templateUrl: 'app/modules/localization/html/localizationList.html',
    providers: [
        LocalizationService,
        HttpClient
    ]
})

export class LocalizationComponent implements OnInit {
    private localizationService :LocalizationService;

    public data :Array<string>;

    constructor(localizationService :LocalizationService) {
        this.localizationService = localizationService;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getLocalization();
    }

    getLocalization(){
        this.localizationService.getLocalization().localizationList.subscribe((data) => {
            this.data = data;
            console.log("DATA:",this.data)
        });
    }
}
```

And service:

```
export class LocalizationService {
    private httpClient :HttpClient;

    public localizationList;

    constructor(httpClient :HttpClient) {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public getLocalization(){
        this.localizationList = this.httpClient.get('localization').map(res => res.json());
        return this;
    }
}
```

And templale:

```
<table class="lst">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Label</th>
        <th>Path</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="#item of data.locales">
        <td>
            <a>{{item.name}}</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{item.path}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I go to this page, I get an error: `EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'locales' of undefined`. At the same time, the console displays a normal object with data. I think this error is due to the fact that he is trying to render the pattern before it receives the data from the service. Is it so? How to make it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to leverage the Elvis operator for this:

```
<tr *ngFor="#item of data?.locales">
    <td>
        <a>{{item.name}}</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        {{item.path}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

after having updating your service:

```
export class LocalizationService {
  private httpClient :HttpClient;

  constructor(httpClient :HttpClient) {
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
  }

  public getLocalization(){
    return this.httpClient.get('localization').map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

and the component:

```
getLocalization(){
  this.localizationService.getLocalization().subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.data = data;
    }
  );
}
```

In fact you can directly return the observable from the service and let the component subscribe on it...

Comment: Thanks, it works) What role is performed by an elvis operator? He points out that the object `data` can be empty?

Comment: The Elvis operator prevents from throwing an undefined error if the element is null... When the element isn't null anymore, the data will be used.